# Kafka mapping message (Using Java Spark)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have kafka topic that contains JSON, example:

```
{"jsonCode":"1234", "jsonData":{.....}}
{"jsonCode":"1234", "jsonData":{.....}}
{"jsonCode":"1235", "jsonData":{.....}}
{"jsonCode":"1235", "jsonData":{.....}}
{"jsonCode":"1236", "jsonData":{.....}}
```

My question is if I can to create the following hash map during the read from topic:

```
["1234", [list of jsonCode 1234 jsons]
["1235", [list of jsonCode 1235 jsons]
["1236", [list of jsonCode 1236 jsons]
```

Its possible? How can I do this mapping?

I want to read from  Kafka using SparkStreamming, to get all unread messages on topic and create the hash map

Thanks.

Comment: What's the key of the Kafka messages? Otherwise, yes, consume all messages, parse the JSON, form a tuple, then groupByKey

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any consumer configuration setup in your code. Consumer config typically requires key and value pairs.

Check while reading from topic, you able to read values in terms of key value pairs. Typically your consumer should be like this:

```
final Consumer<yourKey,yourValue> consumer;  //consumer with consumer config
final ConsumerRecords<String, String> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(pollvals);
   consumerRecords.forEach(record -> {
                System.out.printf("[Consumer Record:(key - %s,value- %s,partition- %d, offset %d)]\n", record.key(),
                        record.value(), record.partition(), record.offset());

                //parse your json from either key or from value
                String value=null;
                 .....     
               value = jsonparser(record.value()); // lets parse from value.
                 ...
```

Comment: That's not Spark